# Can't locate a clickable element by XPATH Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am trying to click on a drop-down menu and then a specific value within menu. I am working with the float range menu at https://buff.163.com/goods/769563?from=market#tab=buying&page_num=1. I've tried using the relative xpath from SelectorsHub and the paintwear_list id, but I keep getting this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
```

Here is the code I am running:

```
floatRange = waitForItem(driver, By.XPATH, "(//div[@class='w-Select-Multi w-Select-scroll black float_range'])[2]", timeout=3)
    floatRange.click()

allBuyOrders = waitForItem(driver, By.XPATH, "//h6[@value='-1~-1']", timeout=3)
allBuyOrders.click()
```

I know the issue isn't that the element hasn't loaded in because I am using webdriverwait through the waitForItem call. Here is the waitForItem function:

```
def waitForItem(driver, selector_type, selector_value, timeout=20, logging=False):
    try:
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((selector_type, selector_value)))
    except selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException:
        if logging:
            print(
                f" > Timeout error: Element couldn't be located. ({selector_value})")
        return None
    return element
```

Here is the HTML:
[image]

I need to click on the "Any" value in the drop-down.

Any ideas?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Please include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Your code snippet is incomplete, and irreproducible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We cannot guess what is inside of the 'waitForItem' method/function.

To select the option 'Any' on the provided website, you first need to expand the dropdown, ensure that it is expanded, and only then do the option selection.

The 'ElementNotInteractableException' exception means that the element is present in the DOM, but the target element state is not reached yet, so you have to wait for a while.

The following code sample works well for me:

```
try:
    driver.get("https://buff.163.com/goods/769563?from=market#tab=buying&page_num=1")

    # open the dropdown
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
        (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#asset_tag-filter-buyOrder div#custom_paintwear_val"))
    ).click()
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(
        (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#asset_tag-filter-buyOrder div#custom_paintwear_val.on"))
    )

    # select the 'Any' option
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
        (By.XPATH, "//div[@id='asset_tag-filter-buyOrder']//ul/li/h6[text()='Any']"))
    ).click()
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

**! EDIT !**

The following code, which utilizes your function, also works:

```
def waitForItem(driver, selector_type, selector_value, timeout=20, logging=False):
    try:
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((selector_type, selector_value)))
    except TimeoutException:
        if logging:
            print(
                f" > Timeout error: Element couldn't be located. ({selector_value})")
        return None
    return element


try:
    driver.get("https://buff.163.com/goods/769563?from=market#tab=buying&page_num=1")

    waitForItem(driver, By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#asset_tag-filter-buyOrder div#custom_paintwear_val").click()
    waitForItem(driver, By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#asset_tag-filter-buyOrder div#custom_paintwear_val.on")
    waitForItem(driver, By.XPATH, "//div[@id='asset_tag-filter-buyOrder']//ul/li/h6[text()='Any']").click()
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: Sorry, I will edit the original question.

Comment: @DallinKump, have you tried the code from above? In your waitForItem function you are using 'presence_of_element_located', it waits for the presence of the element in the DOM, as I mentioned in the answer: the presence of the element doesn't mean that the element is ready to be clicked. I've changed 'presence_of_element_located' to 'element_to_be_clickable' in your function, and everything works for me with the selectors mentioned above. I'll edit my answer to add the example with your function